# 404 error in redirecting(302) post call

Tags: java, http-status-code-302, unirest

```
@POST
@Path("/testmethod")
@CacheControl(maxAge = 1, maxAgeUnit = TimeUnit.DAYS)
@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_HTML)    
public Response TestMethod() throws AppException, ParserConfigurationException,
                SAXException, NullPointerException, JAXBException, ParseException, InvalidKeyException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, UnirestException, ClassNotFoundException{
    cxml = "<payload>dummydetails</payload>";
    signature = "393a4c0990746b221cdb";
    HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://www.example.com")
                        .field("payload", cxml)
                        .field("signature", signature)
                        .asString();
    int status = response.getStatus();
    if(status==302) {
        String loc = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Location");
        javax.ws.rs.core.Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
    }
    else {
        String json = XmlUtil.xmlToJson(response.getBody());
                     ob=XmlUtil.jsonToObj(json);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

                    com.ng.perfiosparams.api.model.response.Error error = XmlUtil.jsonToObj(jsonObject.getString("Error"));
                    if (error.getStatementErrorCode() != null) {
                        ReadXml read = new ReadXml();
                        error.setDescription(read.description(error.getStatementErrorCode()));
                    }
                    error.setResponseType(ResponseType.Error);
                return Response.ok(error).build();    
                }
    }
```

---

> In the above code, the response I am getting in the post call as 302. So, it will go inside **if** condition where it should redirect to location url from header but returning 404 error.
>   May be due to session expired. Can you please help me with this?
>   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You do not have a return in that if, and you didn't tell us what is the variable uri. Looks like you wanted to use the variable loc anyway. Still, you should have concentrated on making your example complete and verifiable (we could run it too and see the same problem you do) and minimal (everything outside the if was completely useless, why is it still there when you're working on your problem?)

Comment: URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(loc).build();
This line of code will be added after String loc line.

Comment: Don't throw random lines, show a complete example all in the same place. Also make an effort to make it complete, verifiable and minimal. Edit your question if needs be. Questions should be as good as they can be and yours isn't, so you should modify it and only refrain from modification after it was made good.